# Why does not update my GridView?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview

My question is about the `ItemTemplateSelector`.

I have a property called `State` in my model and depending on the `State` I apply two differents styles. I use SQLite for the data but the property `State` is marked with the attribute `[ignore]` from SQLite.

I need to change the style when I click the item in the GridView.

```
private void productsDG_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var clickitem = ((Product)e.ClickedItem);
    clickitem.State = true; 
}
```

Changing the state of the GridView does not update the DataTemplate for the item. (The DataTemplate works fine, I tested it with the two states).

The custom data template is:

```
public class CustomDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate defaultTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate unavailable { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Product prod = (Product)item;
        if (prod.State == true)
            return defaultTemplate;

        return unavailable;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your xaml code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clickitem`s class, whatever it is, must implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the `State` property must fire change notification when set. Otherwise WPF won't know you changed the value of the property and won't update the bound control(s). If it doesn't, you *could* call UpdateTarget() on the bound control(s)' BindingExpression after setting `State`, but at that point, does using data binding still make sense?